# Upgrade MacBook Pro Mid 2012 system to Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB (Mac OS Mojave)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, mojave, sata

I have different information related to installation new SSD.

If we will try search through [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0781Z7Y3S) help it shows that the disk Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB will work fine with MacBook Pro 13 inch Mid 2012:

Also I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDWZLPoq__4) where all works good as well for similar system.

But my disk recognized as uninitialized in my Mac OS Mojave 10.14.4 (18E227):

I tried diskutil as well to format my disk and here is an error after some time waiting for creating portion map:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ SAMSUNGSSD disk1
Started erase on disk1
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69825: Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed
```

Also first time there was another error: `error: couldn't open device`

Before this Samsung SSD 860 EVO I have KINGSTON SSD SATA3 240gb disk and all worked good for me. But few days ago Mac OS accidentally crashed and after restart I just saw flashed question-mark folder. I bought new Samsung SSD 860 EVO. Now I am trying to format my Samsung SSD 860 EVO but because of some reason I can't do it not at terminal nor using disk utility.

I read some information about replacing SATA cable, but not sure I need to do it as my previous KINGSTON SATA 3 SSD worked good with the same cable. Maybe port or cable is corrupted I don't know, but not sure if my cable model is different to one that user suggest to buy to make it work:

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/470873/Will+the+Samsung+EVO+860+SATA+III+SSD+drive+work+in+my+system

My System:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd replace the cable. On certain macbooks of that era it was normal to replace the cable when you replaced the dirve. I was unable to locate the specific model.

Comment: got it, I tried to format to another format and looks like it created portion for me. But when I copy file there, it shows an error. I will try cable replacement 

Thanks

Comment: 860 EVO worked for me on a 2011 MBP. Yes, this is different but I do not think it is makes that much difference. SSDs use SATA protocol, which is more or less the same support across devices. I never heard about any compatibilty issues with these SSDs.  I guess the problem is not related to the drive itself.